# android: How to send LinkedHashMap to a URL which is not of a fixed size

Tags: java, android, rest, jsp, android-studio

I have a LinkedHashMap that I want to send to the URL and then get values from it using php.

This is my HashMaP:

```
  for(int i=1;i<=object.length();i++){
                    cartData.put(i,String.valueOf(object.getString(String.valueOf(i))));
                }
```

As you can see the size of "cartData" is not fixed and it depends on the size of the object. I want to know how I can each value of the LinkedHashMap to the url dynamically?

Please help!

Comment: if you share your url paramater name then you will get the solution easily

Comment: please provide full code

Answer (score 1):

Pass the map `myMap.keySet()` and `myMap.entrySet()` seperately and rebuild the map on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use the for each Loop over your HashMap, suppose i have hashmap named **myHashMap** then i can use for each loop to iterate through all HashMap

For dynamically get it until end of the hashmap you can use HashMap's hasNext() method it will iterate through end of hashmap.

```
 for(Integer key : myHashMap.keySet() ){
      String value = myHashMap.get(key);
     }
```

Or you can do this ,

```
Collection c = myHashMap.values();

    //obtain an Iterator for Collection
    Iterator itr = c.iterator();

    //iterate through LinkedHashMap values iterator
    while(itr.hasNext())
        {
          //get the String value here by key
        }
```